# SOAP Operation with same Input and Output Messages Produces Odd Proxy Method Signature

Tags: wcf, visual-studio, wsdl, soapui

I've imported a WSDL File (Checks out fine with SoapUI) and Most of the functions work as expected.

The Problem I'm having is with a few Operations that have the SAME Input Type as Output Type.

Example

```
<operation name="FindID">
    <documentation>Get ID For search</documentation>
    <input message="tns:StringIO"/>
    <output message="tns:StringIO"/>
</operation>
```

Where StringIO message is defined by

```
<message name="StringIO">
    <part name="StringIO" type="xs:string" />
</message>
```

In SOAP UI the FindID Functions works as expected, on the PHP Pages that use this function, it works as expected.

in Visual Studio when I try to call the function, it should be called as

```
string MyResults = WebInterface.FindID(SearchString);
```

as FindID is supposed to Return a string, but instead Visual Studio seems to want to import it as

```
void FindID(ref string SearchString)
```

not

```
string FindID(string SearchString)
```

Now I found a solution (works, but I don't believe it's the "correct" way to do it)
If I create a new message

```
<message name="SecondOutput">
    <part name="SecondOutput" type="xs:string" />
</message>
```

and modify the WSDL Function to

```
<operation name="FindID">
    <documentation>Get ID For search</documentation>
    <input message="tns:StringIO"/>
    <output message="tns:SecondOutput"/>
</operation>
```

Then Visual Studio & SoapUI and the PHP Pages are all happy and behaving normally.

So Why can't I have my Input Message & Output Message as the same type???

Comment: How are you adding it? "Add Service Reference"?

Comment: Adding it by "Add Service Reference" -> Advanced -> Add Web Reference -> URL to web server with WSDL file (Returns 1 Service Found with Service Name)

Comment: And what version of Visual studio are you using?

Comment: Can you please show the binding element from the WSDL?

Comment: <operation name="FindID"><soap:operation soapAction="FindID"/>
  <input>
    <soap:body namespace="http://soap.myserver.com" use="literal" /> 
  </input>
  <output>
    <soap:body namespace="http://soap.myserver.com" use="literal" /> 
  </output>
</operation>

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behaviour.

When you say you expect it to be called as:

```
string MyResults = WebInterface.FindID(SearchString);
```

This appears to be simply an assumption on your part.

There is nothing in the WSDL that would categorically allow you to conclude that. For interoperability purposes, the following two methods are semantically identical:

```
void FindID(ref string);
string FindID(string);
```

The .Net framework uses the WSDL specification to infer the method signatures. The way it chooses between the two equivalents above, is by examining the messages used. Because, the same message is specified for both input and output parameters, .Net is inferring (quite logically IMHO) that the first signature more correctly reflects the service provider's intent.

Comment: The problem I was having with using ref string is that the input value (searchID) is used multiple times in the same sub routine
TestParapaters=GetTest(SearchString);
TestID=FindID(SearhString);

     
And string=FindID(string) is only semantically identical to void(ref string) if you don't care about overwriting you input with the output.
ect..  Using the Ref version, the second command TestID would then return invalid data because SearchString is overwritten (not what I need)

Comment: The issues you raise are implementation details, not things with which WSDL is concerned. I think the naming of the message type itself 'StringIO' (where IO conventially indicates Input and Output) probably assists the conclusion that the method signature generated is probably the closest match possible to the contract.